# Java regex - lost last letter

Tags: java, regex

I have the following Pattern that works with all of my cases:

```
Pattern.compile("((?:[A-Z](?:\\.|(?:(?:\\w|-)[A-Z]))+)\\s*){2,}");
```

The problem is that sometimes, the very last letter gets lost.
The cases are:

```
"By VERA RAMIREZ, MOLLIE RILER and GEORGE SHAW BROWN"
"By LORA D. WOODARD<br/><a href="http://www.test.com/ " target="external">test</a> CEO and President"
"By ANN-ROSE ABRAHAM, Credit.com"
```

Anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: What is the intended use of your pattern? Just those cases, or can you give a more general description?

Comment: Characterize "sometimes".

Comment: I did fix this first issue by adding '+' to the last [A-Z].

Comment: You can answer your own question by using the large textarea down below so that others can quickly find the answer. However, I feel like we can make this expression more efficient if you give us examples of what you would like to match.

Comment: Just curious as to why you use `[A-Z]` several times and `\\w` once.  If it's to support things like DeVILLE, then you might also consider allowing apostrophes.

Comment: But I see another issue: if a name starts with "Dr."+name, I get "r."+name.

Comment: Can you please provide the input, expected and actual output which is misbehaving?

Comment: We need examples of actual input, expected result with explanation why such results are expected and your actual results you get. Without it we can only guess what problem with your code is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two items are causing the engine to stop on an even character boundry.

```
(?: \w | - )
[A-Z]
```

In essence you should change it to

```
(?: \w | - )?
[A-Z]
```

I'm not saying that will fix up all that's probably funky with this regex, but it will get
you the last letter.

I'd take a stab in the dark and say you meant something like this -
**Added exclusion list**

```
 # By KESHA SWEET AP Host Writer
 # "By VERA RAMIREZ, MOLLIE RILER and GEORGE SHAW BROWN"
 # "By LORA D. WOODARD<br/><a href="http://www.test.com/ " target="external">test</a> CEO and President"
 # "By ANN-ROSE ABRAHAM, Credit.com"


 #  "((?:(?!\\b(?:AP|USA|UPS|USPS)\\b)[A-Z](?:\\.|(?:[\\w-]*[A-Z])+))\\s*){2,}(?<!\\s)"

 (                                  # (1 start)
      (?:
           (?!                      # Exclude stuff here
                \b 
                (?: AP | USA | UPS | USPS )
                \b 
           )
           [A-Z] 
           (?:
                \.
             |  
                (?:
                     [\w-]* 
                     [A-Z] 
                )+
           )
      )
      \s* 
 ){2,}                              # (1 end)
 (?<! \s )
```

Comment: I have to have w|- without the * because something like "By KESHA SWEET AP Host Writer" will return "KESHA SWEET AP". But I need "KESHA SWEET".

Comment: What I have now is "((?:[A-Z](?:\\w\\.|\\.|(?:(?:\\w|-)[A-Z]+))+)\\s*){2,}", but the problem now "test ARINE DE VOGUE test" gives me only "ARINE" instead of "ARINE DE VOGUE".

Comment: I would assert that in natural language, you can't write a regex to discern `AP` from a news agency or first/middle/last name. What do you think?

Comment: I hope that I can get with it to a point where I could special case very few cases.

Comment: That's what you would have to do. You could insert it within the regex as a sub-expression group that uses alternations. `(?!\b(?:
AP|USA| etc)\b)`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you for your help. It is nice to get to a resolution with this one.

Comment: Added exclusion list to regex.